# How to extract the integer part of a number using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this xml file:

```
 <pas>
  <rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>DOUBLE</type>
    <oper>HIGH</oper>
    <val1>103619.9</val1>
    <bId>2</bId>
  </rulepar>
  <rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>Text</type>
    <oper>LOW</oper>
    <sumval1>-103.67</sumval1>
    <bId>3</bId>
  </rulepar>
 </pas><rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>Text</type>
    <oper>LOW</oper>
    <val1>10</val1>
    <bId>3</bId>
  </rulepar>
 </pas>
```

with this xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" xml:space="preserve"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="val1|sumval1">  
    <val111><xsl:value-of select="."/></val111>
</xsl:template>
```

when I make my transformation, I have this as result:

```
 <pas>
  <rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>DOUBLE</type>
    <oper>HIGH</oper>
    <val111>103619.9</val111>
    <bId>2</bId>
  </rulepar>
  <rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>Text</type>
    <oper>LOW</oper>
    <val111>-103.67</val111>
    <bId>3</bId>
  </rulepar>
 </pas><rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>Text</type>
    <oper>LOW</oper>
    <val111>10</val111>
    <bId>3</bId>
  </rulepar>
 </pas>
```

I expected normally this output:

```
 <pas>
  <rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>DOUBLE</type>
    <oper>HIGH</oper>
    <val111>103619</val111>
    <bId>2</bId>
  </rulepar>
  <rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>Text</type>
    <oper>LOW</oper>
    <val111>-103</val111>
    <bId>3</bId>
  </rulepar>
 </pas><rulepar>
    <name1>Hi</name1>
    <name2></name2>
    <type>Text</type>
    <oper>LOW</oper>
    <val111>10</val111>
    <bId>3</bId>
  </rulepar>
 </pas>
```

So, how can I do to get only the integer part of the number 103619.9 in the result as shown in the expected output file? I want a solution that can be walk also when the number is only a decimal number and also if this number is <0.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This XPath 1.0 expression gets you the integer part of the number -- regardless if the number is positive or negative**:

```
floor(.)*(. >= 0)    +   ceiling(.) * not(. >= 0)
```

**Explanation**:

1. In case the number is positive we use the `floor()` function.
2. In case the number is negative we use the `ceiling()` function.
3. We combine the two functions (above) using the fact that `number(true()) = 1` and `number(false()) = 0`

**Here is a complete example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="floor(.)*(. >= 0) + ceiling(.) * not(. >= 0)"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <a>2.34</a>
 <b>-3.14</b>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
2
-3
```

Comment: Hello Dimitri, Iwanted to keep the format and the tag name of my xml file. But I could adatp your answer to my problem so that i can get the right solution now. This walk also if the number is negativ and it doesn´t rounded the integer part of the number. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev. Is there any possibility when applying the xsl code above in this xml file:

    <t>
     <a>2.34</a>
     <b>-3.14</b>
     <c>012</c>
    </t>

 
to get this output?

    2
    -3
    012

Thanks.

Comment: @FrankyN., This answer is producing what you want, with the exception that it produces 12 and not 012. In your original question you haven't specified that you want the text nodes to be processed as strings -- on the contrary, you are requesting the "integer part of a number". Please, ask a new, separate question with the new requirement, if this is important to you.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev. Your are right. I already ask a new separate question with the new requirement. The question tag is " **How to keep the format of other number by extracting the integer part of number using xslt?** "

Answer (score 2):

The XPath [`floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/floor) function which

> evaluates a decimal number and returns the largest integer less than or equal to the decimal number

will work if the values are all positive and the XPath would look like

```
<value111><xsl:value-of select="floor(number(.))"/></value111>
```

However, it will not work if the value is `-2.1` for example, as the above code would result in `-3`.

If there is a possibility that a value will be negative then using the [`substring-before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/substring-before) function will work for both positive and negative numbers iff there is only one decimal point.

```
<value111><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/></value111>
```

Note: not sure if the question has a typo but the matching pattern for one of the templates is incorrect. It should be

```
<xsl:template match="val1|sumval1">
```

instead of

```
<xsl:template match="value1|sumval1">
```

Comment: Yes andyb. You get right. It was an error concerning the matching pattern. The correct form is what you proposed. I have already corrected the error in my question. Thank

Comment: Hi andyb. I test my code with your answer and it walks well. But i have some problem withs this. I will reedit my question for more details.

Comment: Yes you are correct, my substring solution would only work if there was always a decimal point. @Dimitre's excellent (as usual!) answer looks like it meets your updated requirements

Comment: Actually, your solution's fairly easy to account for the absence of a decimal point- just do `<xsl:template match="val1[contains(.,'.')] | sumval1[contains(.,'.')]" >`, then only elements that NEED any processing are handled.

Comment: Heh, thanks very much @Flynn1179 I was just working on something similar :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<value111><xsl:value-of select="floor(number(.))"/></value111>
```